# Moving files using VBscript

Tags: file, loops, vbscript, concatenation, move

I am trying to move a group of files with in a group of folders named recup_dir.1 through recup_dir.535 into a single folder so that all the files will be out of the folders and just in the single folder. I know I will need to use a loop to move the files and probably concatenation to go from recup_dir.1 to recup_dir.535 but I just am not that skilled in programming please help!! I just want it to automate the copying and moving of the files rather than do it manually.

Comment: Has my answer solved your problem? If not then please let us know why, otherwise please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (it assumes that you want to bring the files into the directory that you execute the script from):

```
Dim filesys, file
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim i
For i = 0 to 535
     Dim files
     Set files = filesys.GetFolder("recup_dir." & i).Files

    For Each file in files 
          filesys.MoveFile "recup_dir." & i & "\" & file.Name, ".\" & file.Name 'assuming you want all the files to be in the current directory
    Next
Next
```

Of course, please make a backup of all of your folders and files before testing this script.